# Query не возвращает записи

Tags: android, sqlite

Снова открываю вопрос, ранее закрытый мною же.

[Android, SQLite. Query не возвращает записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906096/android-sqlite-query-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8)

Проблема та же, query ничего не возвращает. Мне уже кажется что в моём коде происходит натуральная магия. Названия переменных намерено доведены до абсурда и прописаны тупо в лоб, чтобы бросаться в глаза.

**DBHelper**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE lexicon(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, dd varchar, ddd varchar);");
```

**InsertActivity**

```
public class InsertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText category;
    EditText title;
    Button insert;
    Button show;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        category = findViewById(R.id.category_field);
        title = findViewById(R.id.title_field);
        insert = findViewById(R.id.insert_button);
        show = findViewById(R.id.show_button);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("dd", category.getText().toString());
                cv.put("ddd", title.getText().toString());
                database.insert("lexicon", null, cv);

                Log.i("BASELOG", "INSERED");
            }
        });

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = database.query("lexicon", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                Log.i("BASELOG", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String s = new StringBuilder(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dd"))
                                .append(" ")
                                .append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ddd")))
                                .toString();
                        Log.i("BASELOG", s);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    Log.i("BASELOG", "TABLE NOT FOUND");
                }
            }
        });
```

При нажатии на insert -> INSERED. Данные в формах всегда есть.

При нажатии на show -> сначала 0, потом TABLE NOT FOUND.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, потому что моим нервам пришли кранты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь, автоинкрементируемый столбец идентификатора в андроид должен иметь имя *_id* и никакое другое (не id, Id, ID, _ID и тп.), если вы хотите чтобы классы, работающие с SQLite, собственно, работали.  В частности итерировался курсор. Так же этот столбец должен быть включен в выборку курсора.

Если вы вносите изменения в структуру БД (например, изменяете имена столбцов, добавляете или удаляете таблицы и тп), то тестируемое приложение должно быть деинсталировано на устройстве, чтобы база данных была создана заново. Дело в том, что метод `onCreate()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` вызывается только тогда, когда БД еще не создана, обычно это происходит при первом запуске и далее, когда база уже существует, этот метод больше не вызывается и изменения не применяются. Деинсталяция удалит и базу вместе с приложением.

При изменениях на клиентстких устройствах (которые вы не можете удалить), используется метод `onUpgrade()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` с повышением версии базы данных.